# Missing graduated method: size

Tags: qgis, style

I just can't find the size changing method for the graduated style.

I have an integer containing column, and I would like to display it with icons which are bigger if the value is higher.

So, is this a bug in `QGis v2.14.0` or did I miss some config steps?

[image]

Comment: Is that your screenshot?

Comment: Yes, sure. Why?

Comment: Strange issue. Is that Win 10? Try installing 2.14.1 maybe http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Comment: I tried, but still no other option. May this option is somehow related to the dataset?

Comment: Right, it would be available for points and lines - obviously no polygons

Comment: Thanks, that's an answer. I thought the marker will be automatically a point on the polygon. So, I used `Vector - Geometry Tools - Polygon Centroids` and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Change the polygon shapefiles to point shapefiles and retry.